# Seeking an integral formulation for an algebraic function

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

While working with a generating function for the Catalan numbers, I came across the integral representation
$$\frac1{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{t}}{(t+\frac14)(t-x+\frac14)}\,dt.$$
But, now, I wish to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a similar (real) integral formulation for
> $$\frac1{1+2x+\sqrt{1-4x}}$$
> with "simple" (hopefully linear) factors in the integrand?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt t}{(t + a^2) (t - x + \tfrac14)} \textrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2a + \sqrt{1 - 4x}}$$

So just take $a = \tfrac12 + x$.

Comment: This is nice and upvoted. But, is there some other ones with linear factors?

Comment: Generalising a bit further we have $$\frac 1{\pi \csc {k \pi}} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{(t+a)(t+b)} \textrm{d}t = \frac{a^k - b^k}{a - b}$$ and $$\frac 1{\pi \csc {k \pi}} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{(t+a)(t+b)(t+c)} \textrm{d}t = \frac{a^k (b - c) + b^k (c - a) + c^k (a - b)}{(a - b)(b - c)(c - a)}$$ but I'm not seeing how to use those to get the desired form with linear factors.